# loading a certificate from keystore

Tags: java, certificate

Load a certificate  and keys from keystore which is password protected and then use it for cert verification and digital signing

Answer (score 6):

To read the certificate is really trivial.

```
CertificateFactory factory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");  
X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate) factory.generateCertificate(new FileInputStream("file.pem"));
```

This is with standard APIs (in try/catch) etc and you have loaded your certificate.
Now the `toString` method of certificate is not suitable for you since it just captures the "user's" view of the certificate e.g. you would use it for `println` for instance
Can't you send the certificate object itself?
Not sure what your server expects so you can look into the various methods of certificate
[X509Certificate](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/security/cert/X509Certificate.html%20X509Certificate)

Answer (score 2):

I use this code

```
    PEMReader pr=new PEMReader(new StringReader(trust_certs));
    KeyStore trustStore  = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    trustStore.load(null, null);
    Object o;
    int i=0;
    while((o=pr.readObject())!=null){
        if(o instanceof X509Certificate){
            i++;
            X509Certificate c=(X509Certificate)o;
            trustStore.setCertificateEntry(Integer.toString(i), c);
        }
    }
```

http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.6/org/bouncycastle/openssl/PEMReader.html

Answer (score 0):

A pem file is read as any other text file. Read the [Java tutorial about IO](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/) (and concentrate on character streams, since a pem file contains text, and on File IO, since this is what you want to do)