# Use PEM Encoded CA Cert on filesystem directly for HTTPS request?

Tags: java, x509certificate, keystore, pem

This is similar to [Import PEM into Java Key Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138940/import-pem-into-java-key-store). But the question's answers use OpenSSL for conversions and tools to import them into key stores on the file system.

I'm trying to use a well formed X509 certificate as a trust anchor:

```
static String CA_FILE = "ca-rsa-cert.pem";

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    ks.load(new FileInputStream(CA_FILE), null);

    TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory
                .getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    tmf.init(ks);

    SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

    // Redirected through hosts file
    URL url = new URL("https://example.com:8443");

    HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url
            .openConnection();
    connection.setSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());

    ...
}
```

When I attempt to run the program, I get an error:

```
$ java TestCert 
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:650)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:55)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1214)
    at TestCert.main(TestCert.java:30)
```

I also tried `KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PEM");` and `getInstance("X509");`, but they did not work either.

I know Java supports PEM and DER encoded certificates because that's what a web server sends to a client. But none of the [`KeyStoreType`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#KeyStore)'s seem to match my needs, so I suspect I'm not using the right APIs for this.

The reasons I want to use them directly and *not* import them into a long-lived `KeyStore` are:

1. There are hundreds of PEM certs to test
2. The certs are on my filesystem
3. Using certs from the filesystem matches my workflow
4. I don't want to to use `openssl` or `keytool`
5. I don't want to perform key store maintenance

How does on take a well formed PEM encoded certificate on the filesystem and use it directly?

Comment: What do you mean by "I know Java support PEM encoded certificates because that's what a web server sends to a client"?

Comment: Thanks Mike. Well, I'm not sure how to answer. Where does the confusion lie?

Comment: Certificates sent on the wire in a client/web server secure transaction like TLS 1.1/1.2 are typically sent DER-encoded without the use of PEM. This is because PEM (Base64) uses 4 bytes for every 3 bytes of binary data increasing the size of the DER-encoded binary value by at least 25%.

Comment: Also worth mentioning is that the [`CertificateFactory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/cert/CertificateFactory.html#generateCertificate(java.io.InputStream)) allows you to generate certificates from either plain DER or PEM format. You could use the `CertificateFactory` to create an `Certificate` object, typecast it into an `X509Certificate` and try loading that into your `KeyStore`.

Comment: Good point Mike. I forgot all about that. (And I had no luck with a DER encoded certificate, either).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer while trying to do this another way at [Set certificate for KeyStore.TrustedCertificateEntry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22494763/set-certificate-for-keystore-trustedcertificateentry). Its based on Vit Hnilica's answer at [loading a certificate from keystore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7140242/loading-a-certificate-from-keystore). I"m going to leave the question with this answer since most Stack Overflow answers start with "convert with `openssl`, then use `keytool` ...".

```
String CA_FILE = ...;

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(CA_FILE);
X509Certificate ca = (X509Certificate) CertificateFactory.getInstance(
        "X.509").generateCertificate(new BufferedInputStream(fis));

KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
ks.load(null, null);
ks.setCertificateEntry(Integer.toString(1), ca);

TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory
        .getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
tmf.init(ks);
...
```