# Set certificate for KeyStore.TrustedCertificateEntry?

Tags: java, x509certificate, keystore

I'm trying to skin this cat: [Use PEM Encoded CA Cert on filesystem directly for HTTPS request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22493997/use-pem-encode-ca-cert-on-filesystem-directly-for-https-request) another way.

Java has a class `KeyStore.TrustedCertificateEntry`, but I can't figure out how to load a certificate into it. My code looks similar to below:

```
import java.security.KeyStore.TrustedCertificateEntry;
...

X509Certificate ca = (X509Certificate) CertificateFactory(...);
KeyStore ks = TrustedCertificateEntry(ca);
```

And:

```
X509Certificate ca = (X509Certificate) CertificateFactory(...);
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.TrustedCertificateEntry(ca);
```

And:

```
X509Certificate ca = (X509Certificate) CertificateFactory(...);
KeyStore ks = new KeyStore.TrustedCertificateEntry(ca);
```

And:

```
X509Certificate ca = (X509Certificate) CertificateFactory(...);
KeyStore ks = new KeyStore.TrustedCertificateEntry(ca);
```

The program fails to compile with errors similar to:

```
SuperCert.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
KeyStore ks = TrustedCertificateEntry(ca);
                ^
  symbol:   method TrustedCertificateEntry(X509Certificate)
  location: class TestCert
```

After loading my X509 cert into the `KeyStore`, I plan on using it in a `TrustManagerFactory` and ultimately fetching a web page with `HttpsURLConnection`.

How does one load a `X509Certificate` into a `TrustedCertificateEntry`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found it based on Vit Hnilica's answer at [loading a certificate from keystore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7140242/loading-a-certificate-from-keystore). I"m going to leave the question with this answer since most Stack Overflow answers start with "convert with `openssl`, then use `keytool` ...".

Hat's off to Vit for posting that answer. Hnilica's answer is the only one I found after wading through pages of similar questions and answers on Stack Overflow.

```
String CA_FILE = ...;

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(CA_FILE);
X509Certificate ca = (X509Certificate) CertificateFactory.getInstance(
        "X.509").generateCertificate(new BufferedInputStream(fis));

KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
ks.load(null, null);
ks.setCertificateEntry(Integer.toString(1), ca);

TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory
        .getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
tmf.init(ks);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is also another approach.

```
CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate) certificateFactory.generateCertificate(new FileInputStream(file));
keyStore.setEntry(alias, new KeyStore.TrustedCertificateEntry(certificate), null);
```

ProtectionParameter for TrustedCertificateEntry should be null.